# How do I get function parameters from bind()?

Tags: function, parameters, gdb

When using `gdb`, I often get a nice list of parameters passed to functions. However, with certain functions like `bind`, I do not get the parameters:

```
(gdb) break bind
Breakpoint 1 at 0x404b40
(gdb) r
...
Breakpoint 1, bind () at ../sysdeps/unix/syscall-template.S:82
82      in ../sysdeps/unix/syscall-template.S
(gdb) bt
#0  bind () at ../sysdeps/unix/syscall-template.S:82
...
```

How can I still get the parameters passed to these functions?

Comment: What OS are you using? x64 or x86? The answer depends on architecture.

Comment: x86_64, but I'd be interested in x86 as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`bind` is one of socket system calls. There is a special way to put breakpoints on system calls in gdb - `catch syscall <syscall name>`. After this kind of breakpoint hit, you can watch syscall parameters in registers according to [kernel calling conventions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2538212/72178). For x86_64, parameters are passed via %rdi, %rsi, %rdx, %r10, %r8 and %r9 registers. For x86-32 - via %ebx, %ecx, %edx, %esi, %edi, %ebp registers.

```
(gdb) catch syscall bind 
Catchpoint 3 (syscall 'bind' [49])
(gdb) r
Starting program: /usr/bin/nmap google.com

Starting Nmap 5.00 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2012-03-16 01:09 PDT
Warning: Hostname google.com resolves to 6 IPs. Using 173.194.69.100.

Catchpoint 3 (call to syscall 'bind'), 0x00007ffff6520307 in bind ()
   from /lib/libc.so.6
(gdb) info registers 
rax            0xffffffffffffffda   -38
rbx            0xb35870 11753584
rcx            0xffffffffffffffff   -1
rdx            0x14 20
rsi            0x7fffffff7d90   140737488321936
rdi            0x8  8
rbp            0x8  0x8
rsp            0x7fffffff7d58   0x7fffffff7d58
r8             0xb  11
r9             0x8000   32768
r10            0x7fffffff7b00   140737488321280
r11            0x202    514
r12            0xb09630 11572784
r13            0xb359f0 11753968
r14            0x2  2
r15            0xc8 200
rip            0x7ffff6520307   0x7ffff6520307 <bind+7>
eflags         0x202    [ IF ]
cs             0x33 51
ss             0x2b 43
ds             0x0  0
es             0x0  0
fs             0x0  0
---Type <return> to continue, or q <return> to quit---
gs             0x0  0
(gdb)
```

For example here %rdi contains first `bind` call parameter - socket file descriptor.

For x86-32 things are more complicated as socket system calls are implemented via `socketcall` system call. Thats why it's impossible to put catchpoint directly to `bind`. You can find more info about it [here](http://jkukunas.phpnet.us/2010/05/23/x86-linux-networking-system-calls-socketcall/).